# Equivalents of AVAudioSession inputLatency and outputLatency properties on macOS

Tags: macos, core-audio, avaudiosession

Can't find the exact equivalents of [AVAudioSession.inputLatency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616537-inputlatency) and [AVAudioSession.outputLatency](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616500-outputlatency) on macOS. Any idea how to get or calculate these?

A subquestion also: on MacCatalyst `AVAudioSession.inputLatency` returns 0.0, though `outputLatency` returns something else and looks normal. Why?

Comment: I'm not sure whether they're exact equivalents but the sum of `kAudioDevicePropertyLatency` and `kAudioStreamPropertyLatency` provide latency information if you have access to the `AudioObjectID`

Comment: Are you using IOProcs or AUHAL?  There has been discussions about calculating it on the core-audio mailing list, e.g. this response from Jeff Moore (Jan 6, 2010): https://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2010/Jan/msg00046.html (basically, the stream/device latencies plus device safety offset).